# Why doesn't WCFTestclient understand standard EF objects but understands STE objects

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4, self-tracking-entities

When I try to consume a WCF service which expose operations that return standard EF objects I receive a warning on these operations. The warning states "This operation is not supported in the WCF Test Client because it uses type < EntityName >". The generated source code for the entities in my EF model contains ordinary C# classes, inherited from EntityObject and decorated with [EdmEntityType],[Serializable] and [DataContract] attribute.

If I change the standard code generation process and instead produce Self Tracking Entities (STE) I receive classes which are also decorated with the DataContract attribute but they don't inherit from EntityObject anymore. WCF Operations that return STE objects ARE supported by the WCFTestClient.

**What is it in EntityObject that prevent WCFTestClient from calling / displaying these operations?**

EntityObject is also decorated with [Serializable] and [DataContract].

I know there are other tools besides WCFTestClient that I could use and I have already coded my own testclient but I'm curious of why it behaves like this.

Comment: did you get any answer?