# Using custom classes in WCF Test Client

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

As part of my WCF web service's return message I created three custom classes. They are implemented in my the return message class, which contains a `DataContract` decoration (pretty sure that's how it's supposed to be done).

However when I run the Visual Studio 2012 WCF Test Client I get the following error message (highlighted in black)

[image]

**App Code**

Class exposed to the program calling the web service. This calls a method with a return type of `CloneMessage` (detailed below)

```
namespace OKeeffeDataService
{
    public class MonetToDss : IMonetToDss
    {
        private AgentCloneRules _agentClone;

        public MonetToDss()
        {
            _agentClone = new AgentCloneRules();
        }

        [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "AgentPaymentUpdater")]
        public CloneMessage CloneRequest(string agentId)
        {
            //TODO: Validate agent Id?
            EventLog.WriteEntry("OKeeffe", "Made it to CloneRequest", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            return _agentClone.CloneRequest(agentId);
        }
    } 
}
```

**App Code Interface**

```
namespace OKeeffeDataService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMonetToDss
    {
        [OperationContract]
        CloneMessage CloneRequest(string agentId);
    }

}
```

**Clone Message Class**

This is the class the WCF service returns. The `AgentClone` and `RelationshipCode` classes were generated by the Entity Framework and extend `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject`. `AgentAddresses` is a custom class I wrote with standard `string` properties representing Street, City, State, Zip, etc (listed below).

```
namespace BusinessEntities
{
    [DataContract]
    public class CloneMessage : ICloneMessage
    {
        [DataMember]
        public AgentClone AgentInformation { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public IList<AgentAddress> AgentAddresses { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public IList<RelationshipCode> RelationshipCodes { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public CloneMessage(){}

        public CloneMessage(AgentClone agtTran, IList<AgentAddress> addresses, IList<RelationshipCode> relationshipCodes)
        {
            this.AgentInformation = agtTran;
            this.AgentAddresses = addresses;
            this.RelationshipCodes = relationshipCodes;
        }
    }
}
```

**Clone Message Interface**

```
namespace BusinessEntities
{
    public interface ICloneMessage
    {
        AgentClone AgentInformation { get; set; }
        IList<AgentAddress> AgentAddresses { get; set; }
        IList<RelationshipCode> RelationshipCodes { get; set; }
        String ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Adding the enum and classes to the post

**AgentAddresses class**

`AddressType` is custom enum.

```
namespace BusinessEntities
{
    [DataContract]
    public class AgentAddress : IAgentAddress
    {
        [DataMember]
        public AddressTypeValues.AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Street1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Street3 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**AddressTypeValues enum**

```
namespace BusinessEntities
{
    public class AddressTypeValues
    {
        [DataContract(Name = "AddressType")]
        public enum AddressType
        {
            [EnumMember(Value = "Home")]
            Home,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Mailing")]
            Mailing,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Location")]
            Location,
            [EnumMember(Value = "Other")]
            Other
        }
    }
}
```

**AgentClone and RelationshipCode class headers**

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="AgentResourcesReturn", Name="AgentClone")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class AgentClone : EntityObject

[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="AgentResourcesReturn", Name="RelationshipCode")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class RelationshipCode : EntityObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following known types to your CloneMessage data contract.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(AgentClone))]
[KnownType(typeof(AgentAddress))]
[KnownType(typeof(RelationshipCode))]
public class CloneMessage : ICloneMessage
```

And this AddressTypeValues type to the AgentAddress  class.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(AddressTypeValues))]
public class AgentAddress : IAgentAddress
```

Once you do this, rebuild the service and try to browse it again the WCF test client.

Comment: the enum known type was missing.. can you add that and try again?

Comment: Added both and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

1. Add DataContract attribute to AgentClone & RelationshipCode classes
2. If AddressTypeValues.AddressType is Enum type, then apply the DataContractAttribute attribute to the type. You must then apply the EnumMemberAttribute attribute to each member that must be included in the data contract. refer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875(v=vs.110).aspx
3. Add the below attributes to CloneMessage class
   [KnownType(typeof(AgentAddress))]
   [KnownType(typeof(RelationshipCode))]
4. try changing like this..

   ```
   namespace BusinessEntities
   {
       [DataContract(Name = "AddressType")]
       public enum AddressType
       {
           [EnumMember(Value = "Home")]
           Home,
           [EnumMember(Value = "Mailing")]
           Mailing,
           [EnumMember(Value = "Location")]
           Location,
           [EnumMember(Value = "Other")]
           Other
       }
    }
   ```

   [DataMember]
   public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
5. If you are still facing issue, then I am 100% sure that the problem is with AgentInformation/RelationshipCodes. Just comment these two members of CloneMessage class and try. you will get some pointers. If you don't face issue after commenting, then it is something to do with EntityObject. similar issue - [Why doesn't WCFTestclient understand standard EF objects but understands STE objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278793/why-doesnt-wcftestclient-understand-standard-ef-objects-but-understands-ste-obj)

Comment: `AgentClone` and `RelationshipCode` already contain `[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]`. Is the `DataContract` still necessary and if so does it matter if it is listed above/below this decoration?

Comment: Already done that as well. Someone suggested the `KnownType` attributes being added to `CloneMessage`, so I did that (for all three classes) and still get the same error.

Comment: added some more info about the enum and `EntityObject` classes to the post.

Comment: This wouldn't compile (not sure if you meant for the `DataMember` be a property of the class `AddressTypeValues` or the namespace but tried both). Could this be because I am using the Entity Framework to generate the `AgenClone` and `RelationshipCode` classes?